# OpenXML can you combine DOM and SAX approach to save a worksheet?

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I created a simple wrapper-library for OpenXML to be able to write values to cells, style cells and create some simple graphs. I used the SAX-like approach with an `OpenXmlWriter` to write cell values but want to also add charts which I am creating with the DOM approach.

My issue is, when the file is saved, none of the information written by the `OpenXmlWriter` is actually in the sheet XML file and it only contains the drawing.

Is there any way I could combine writing the sheet XML both with an `OpenXmlWriter` and have the charts without changing the chart code to SAX as well?

Here is some code (condensed for brevity):

```
public void createSpreadsheet(string filePath)
{
    // Init spreadsheet document file.
    var spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filePath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

    // Create and add a workbook.
    var workBookPart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
    workBookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

    // Create a worksheet.
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workBookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();

    var sheets = workBookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

    // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
    Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = workBookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = name };
    sheets.Append(sheet);

    // Create a drawing for charts.
    var drawingsPart = worksheetPart.AddNewPart<DrawingsPart>();
    worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(new Drawing() { Id = worksheetPart.GetIdOfPart(m_drawingsPart) });
    worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

    // Create a worksheet drawing to nest the anchor objects for the charts
    drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing = new WorksheetDrawing();

    // Add chart.
    ChartPart chartPart = worksheet.drawingsPart.AddNewPart<ChartPart>();
    //... few hundred lines of code adding all chart elements.

    // Write cell values.
    XLWriter.writeWorksheetPart(worksheetPart);

    // Close document.
    spreadsheetDocument.Dispose();
}


internal class XLWriter
{
    public static void writeWorksheetPart(WorksheetPart worksheetPart, XLWorksheet worksheet)
    {
        OpenXmlWriter oxw = OpenXmlWriter.Create(worksheetPart);
        oxw.WriteStartElement(worksheetPart.Worksheet);
        oxw.WriteStartElement(new SheetData());

        oxw.WriteStartElement(new Row());

        // Cache the column name to avoid calling the bijective numeration function if possible.
        int cachedColumnIndex = -1;
        string cachedColumnName = "";

        foreach (XLCell cell in worksheet.cells)
        {
            if (cell.column != cachedColumnIndex)
            {
                cachedColumnIndex = cell.column;
                cachedColumnName = BijectiveNumeration.toBijective(cell.column);
            }

            List<OpenXmlAttribute> attributes = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();
            attributes.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("r", null, cachedColumnName + cell.row.ToString()));
            writeCellValue(oxw, cell, attributes);
        }

        oxw.WriteEndElement();

        oxw.WriteEndElement();
        oxw.WriteEndElement();

        oxw.Close();
    }

    private static void writeCellValue(OpenXmlWriter oxw, XLCell cell, List<OpenXmlAttribute> attributes)
    {
        switch (cell.value.type)
        {
            case XLCellValueType.Number:
                attributes.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("t", null, "n"));
                oxw.WriteStartElement(new Cell(), attributes);
                oxw.WriteElement(new CellValue(cell.value.value));
                oxw.WriteEndElement();
                break;
            case XLCellValueType.Boolean:
                attributes.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("t", null, "b"));
                oxw.WriteStartElement(new Cell(), attributes);
                oxw.WriteElement(new CellValue(cell.value.value == 1 ? "1" : "0"));
                oxw.WriteEndElement();
                break;
            case XLCellValueType.Text:
                attributes.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("t", null, "str"));
                oxw.WriteStartElement(new Cell(), attributes);
                oxw.WriteElement(new CellValue(cell.value.text));
                oxw.WriteEndElement();
                break;
            case XLCellValueType.Date:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```